# PushKit Framework, How does it work?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, sip, voip

My understanding of iOS SIP application or say VOIP application is:

It is a persistent TCP connection between server & device. As soon as call request comes it establishes RTP connection with server to other devices. Now you can exchange voice or other packets on this connection & have a real time call.

With Push Kit framework, I am confused that how exactly it is suppose to work?

Questions:

1. When app goes to background is My VOIP TCP connection still there or it is closed?
2. If it is closed, after getting VOIP APNS, how exactly the SIP protocol works with out its main TCP connection?
3. Do we have to establish connection when a VOIP APNS comes in? What if at that time establishing TCP fails due to some reason.
4. What kind of changes we have to do in SIP server to achieve this?

May be my whole understanding is wrong here. But I want to know the flow architecture about how exactly a VOIP application works with APNS.

I tried looking into various articles over internet, but all I understood about Push-Kit's VOIP-APNS is that it will wakeup your application in background, but they fails to clarify my above questions.

Can anyone throw some light on this topic please.

Comment: I thought many people have started working on PushKit given by iOS is there anyone help me understand the data flow in this?

Comment: Hi Atanu have you figured out the answers to your questions? I'm trying to understand exactly the same things you asked here.

Comment: No not yet, I didn't got much time to look into this by myself. And I don't see any answer here from 2 months :(

Comment: If you are already into VOIP apps for iOS I would like to have a chat with you on that, if possible.

Comment: I believe you close all connection when the app goes into background. Upon recieving the push notification, you open a connection and start the call

Comment: any light to this question? did you had the time to investigate further?

Comment: @ymotov have a look on answer, I hope this will help!

Comment: @DashAndRest No longer working on that app, but thanks for clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

> 1 When app goes to background is My VOIP TCP connection still there or it is closed?

Yes and No, when app goes background on iOS 9 or older then it will stay connected if you programmed so, i.e here are chances of having TCP connection live.
But in iOS 10, app will never be alive in any condition once it is in background, i.e. there is no scope of having TCP connection live.

> 2 If it is closed, after getting VOIP APNS, how exactly the SIP protocol works with out its main TCP connection?
>   3 Do we have to establish connection when a VOIP APNS comes in? What if at that time establishing TCP fails due to some reason.

Once app is in background and TCP connection is closed, after receiving PushKit notification iOS will awake app and that time we need to run the code snippet to again make TCP connection to server.
If TCP connection fails this time, then user will not be able to get voice and we need to again run the code snippet to connect TCP.

> 4 What kind of changes we have to do in SIP server to achieve this?

For server side, it's exactly same like APNS(regular push notifications). See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557570/pushkit-for-voip-ios-apps)