# PushKit for VOIP iOS apps

Tags: ios, voip, pushkit

Maybe this is a trivial question, however it is not yet clear to me if the server side is impacted when `PushKit` frameworks will be applied in a `VoIP` iOS app.

The `SIP` server for example sends an INVITE to my app, the notification is received in the app and the call is established.

Is the server impacted when `PushKit.framework` is used? Who is sending the pushkit event? The `SIP` server or Apple? Is this similar to `APNS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly like APNS as far as the server is concerned. It just comes with added benefits for the client (the iOS app).

The client registers with the Apple servers and gets a token in return. The app registers the token with your server. Your SIP server can use the token to send the notification with the appropriate payload. That is sent to APNS which then forwards it to the device.

Comment: So the SIP server has to inform Apple and then Apple will push the notification to the device. Can you share a document that officially says this?

Comment: That is the only way it can work. Only apple can send you push notifications since it maintains a persistent connection with the devices. The only other way is for the client to maintain a persistent connection with your server and notify the client in case of an invite. Then the client will generate a local notification for the event. However this is not recommended by apple. Reference- https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html

Comment: I would recommend reading up on the basics of how push notifications to work for better understanding- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html Like I said before conceptually the pushkit notifications work exactly like normal notifications as far as the server is concerned.